# python import (project organization)

Tags: python, import, organization

I am working on a python project and have generated tons of python scripts. I would like to put them in different directories for organization. My question is how can I import scripts form parent directories.

I want to be able to do

`import ../utl/server.py`

How can I achieve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this as:

```
from ..utl import server
```

However, note that that kind of relative import works only in certain situations. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more details).

Comment: how about something like `from ../utl/server import connect, disconnect`?

Comment: No, it would be `from ..utl.server import connect, disconnect`

Answer (score 2):

You can append to your PYTHONPATH and import it normally like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..') # using an absolute path may be more robust.
import server
```